# Pelican site with tags and categories list

Tags: python, static-site, pelican

I have a blog on WordPress that I'm migrating to the pelican. Each post currently has 1 category associated with it. and each post has multiple tags. I'm in the middle and struggling with few things.

I'm able to retrieve all the post data from Wordpress and associate with them appropriately on the new site. but the problem I'm facing here is how can I create tags and category page?.
if you visit https://www.example.com/tags/python, it should list all the posts that have Python tag and ideally, this page should look like home page design.

Similarly, I want to implement for categories.

you can use Stackoverflow theme(basic version) to visualize what I'm trying to build: 
Mostly care about tags, category and search. so when you click on a tag it would open a page `https://www.example.com/tags/<tag>`

Also, on a similar note, if someone can recommend the best plugin for search that I can use with pelican theme. this will search across all the posts on the site.

Answer (score 5):

Pelican creates per-tag and category pages by default. As an example, you can see them by first generating the sample content:

```
# Following assumes Pelican is installed and source is in: ~/Projects/pelican
cd ~/Projects/pelican/samples/
pelican content -s pelican.conf.py -o ~/Desktop/ptest
cd ~/Desktop/ptest
python -m http.server
open http://localhost:8000/
```

Once the browser tab has loaded, tap the "Misc" menu item (http://localhost:8000/category/misc.html) to see posts in that category. Similarly, the following link should show all posts tagged with "bar": http://localhost:8000/tag/bar.html

Ultimately, how this is supported will depend on the chosen theme, but most themes should support this basic built-in functionality.

Regarding site search, you might try: https://github.com/MTecknology/pelican-search

Comment: Can I assist you further with your question? If not, would you please consider accepting this answer?

Answer (score 0):

For Search: I use `pelican-algolia` for my [tech blog](https://cloudbytes.dev). You can install by running

```
pip install pelican-algolia
```

The [pelican-algolia GitHub repo](https://github.com/rehanhaider/pelican-algolia) has detailed documentation, and a short tutorial on how to configure [algolia for pelican](https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/launching-pelican-algolia-plugin-for-pelican).